# State not updating within a promised fetch (react)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, promise, fetch

I have a form with which i am sending data to my api. The data is used to create backend admin accounts and also create post entries. I need to post the data in a **certain order** to get some dynamic fields from the admin account to the post. For example:

1. create the admin account to make an id field
2. use the id field and apply to the post to create a unique link between admin account and post

Everything works apart from **one state update** that i'm trying to do after fetching the freshly created account:

```
// dont know what the ID will be as its dynamic

const [theID, setTheID] = useState('');

//Send the data to firstly create the admin account (works fine)

fetch('example.com/api/cockpit/saveUser', {
        method: 'post',
        headers: { 
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Cockpit-Token': process.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY
            },
        body: JSON.stringify({
            user: {
                user: firstname.toLowerCase()+surname.toLowerCase(),
                name: firstname,
                email: email,
                password: password,
                group: 'consumers',
            }
        })
    })
    .then(user => user.json())

    // make next fetch a chain of the promise
    // fetch all accounts but filter by email so will only return the right one

    .then(()=>{
        return fetch(`example.com/api/cockpit/listUsers&filter[email]=${email}`,{
            method: 'post',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Cockpit-Token': process.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY
            }
        })
    })
    .then((res) => {
        return res.json();
    })
    .then((res)=>{
        // the console log works fine
        console.log(res[0]._id);
        // the state returns undefined
        setTheID(res[0]._id);
    })
    .catch((err)=>{
        console.error(err);
    })

    //Then last fetch to make the post entry works fine ...
      .then(()=>{
        return fetch('example.com/api/collections/save/consumers', {
            method: 'post',
            headers: {
                 'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                 'Accept': 'application/json',
                 'Cockpit-Token': process.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY,
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                data: {
                    firstname: firstname,
                    surname: surname,
                    password: password,
                    email: email,
                    project_name: projectName,
                    project_template: tmp,
                    // expected to get the dynamic ID front the state
                    ass_consumer: theID,
                    slug: projectName.toLowerCase().replace(' ','') + '-rr',
                    username: firstname.toLowerCase()+surname.toLowerCase()
                }
            })
        })
    })
    .then(user => user.json())
    .then((user)=>{
        setnewPage(user._id);
    })
```

I've checked the console which shows up fine after fetching. All my other state changes are bound to the form inputs but i've never had this problem with updating state in a fetch before.

I've also tried creating a function that takes the email as an argument then returns the state change but no luck with that either.

Appreciate any help!

(using cockpit as my api)

**EDIT**

This is what the console log returns:
(i just need the _id)

```
{
 user: "johndoe", 
 name: "john", 
 email: "john.doe@example.com", 
 active: true, 
 group: "consumers", 
 _created: 1627039008,
 _id: "60faa5203365618a38000035",
 _modified: 1627039008,
}
```

Comment: So `console.log(res[0]._id)` prints out the correct id but when you check the result of `setTheID` it is `undefined`? Where and when do you check the result of the state?

Comment: you are ignoring the result of `res.json()` the first time, is it intentional? are you fetching the correct email?

Comment: You say that "the state returns undefined", but you're just setting the state, not reading it. Where does the state actually return undefined?  If you try reading the state within the same function, the changes will probably not be reflected yet, so it's important to see the code snippet where you actually try to read the state.

Comment: @MarcoNisi So right after there is one last fetch which applies the data to the post entry and is supposed to get the id from the account just fetched. Everything gets posted once the form submit button is clicked all at once - I know its working because all the fields are being populate to both the account and post, apart from that one id.

And yes if i just check for the result for my setTheID state its undefined

Comment: @snwmn can you post this last fetch?

Comment: @Kozie I Set the state to be empty at the start as i dont know the value until the first fetch has been completed and the id has been generated. Then in the fetch after trying to set the state, you can see where im trying to apply the state to 'ass_consumer'

Comment: @SamridhTuladhar Yes the correct email is being fetched as when i console log, the users details appear correct

Comment: Why not use the response from the first fetch and pass the ID from the response to the second fetch, then set the states at the very end?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You are most likely reading the state within the same operation ("too quickly"), so the state changes will not be reflected yet because the process to update React state is asynchronous.

You have 2 options to always get the most up to date state value:

- Either use a reference to the state (check out this [package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-usestateref))
- Or use an "ugly" work-around taking the value from setState like this:

(*Edit*: While the solution below may work, it often produces unexpected behaviour and is very bad practice since setState callbacks should be pure. If you rely on a state changing before performing a certain action, using `useEffect` is probably the way to go)

```
    const [id, setId] = useState("")

    setId("test")
    console.log(id) // ""

    // do this to get the up to date value, as the value 
    // in setState is always the most up to date one
    let idVal
    setId(current => {
     idVal = current
     return current
     })
    console.log(idVal) // "test"
```

So in your specific example, try this:

```
    //Then last fetch to make the post entry works fine ...
  .then(()=>{
    let customerID
    setTheID(current => {
      customerID = current
      return current
    })
    return fetch('example.com/api/collections/save/consumers', {
        method: 'post',
        headers: {
             'Content-Type': 'application/json',
             'Accept': 'application/json',
             'Cockpit-Token': process.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY,
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
      
            data: {
                [...]
                // use the customerID variable, not the state variable
                ass_consumer: customerID,
               [...]
            }
        })
    })
})
```

Comment: You're right! it was trying to change state before it had a chance to update, this solution works for me, thanks! - will remember this next time i run into this type of problem